# IBM MQ Topic String subscription and filter

Tags: ibm-mq, middleware, mq, jms-topic

If I have a topic tree like
- Sports/NBA/
- Sports/NHL/

and If I  would like to get the notifications for every NBA Team I would subscribe to a topic string like: Sports/NBA/*

But what if I'm not interested in 2 Teams from the whole list ?

If there a way of filtering out some topic objects when subscribing to the Topic like  Sports/NBA/*/-Lakers or something like that ?

Thanks for any advice

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checked with IBM Support, this is not supported.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible by only using topic strings, but you could specify a selector when creating the subscription to filter out the teams you need. But to allow you to use a selector you would need to set message properties to filter on when sending the messages.

http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_8.0.0/com.ibm.mq.ref.adm.doc/q084220_.htm

http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_7.0.1/com.ibm.mq.csqzal.doc/fg20160_.htm

http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_8.0.0/com.ibm.mq.dev.doc/q022920_.htm